# Как сделать интерактивные подсказки в приложении?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Когда первый раз запускаешь некоторые приложения, в ходе работы затменяется экран и появляются подсказки над элементами экрана: Зажмите элемент, чтобы его удалить, и тд. Ранее для этого была библиотека ShowcaseView, но она уже неактуальна, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score -1):

Решил вопрос благодаря Intro Showcase View.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]